# Импорт фигуры из blender в Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

Стандартная фигура + post processing в самом блендере

Хочу получить точно такую же фигуру в THREE.js

Гипотеза: увеличить ширину ребер и дать им черный цвет. Но как?
делаю импорт в .json

```
function init1() {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('bird3.json', addModel)
}


function addModel(geometry, materials) {
    var material_m = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial (materials);
    var model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material_m);
    console.log(materials);
    scene.add(model)
}
```

Помогите, программеры добрые

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выложите код с HTML, пример что есть у вас

Comment: А какая версия Three.js используется? `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial()` уже давно отсутствует во фреймворке.

Comment: @prisoner849 
https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js
вот отсюда брал, кажется, r88
с видео код брал, поэтому так)
чем теперь лучше пользоваться?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чем не устраивает [икосаэдр](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/IcosahedronGeometry) из Three.js, что его надо импортировать из блендера?